# Pass Apache environment variable to Django site on server

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to set some Apache environment variables, and then pass them to `os.environ` when Apache loads my application.

In my VirtualHost I set:

```
    SetEnv USER user
```

I my `.wsgi` file I do:

```
    path = "/home/ubuntu/project/myapp/"
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

    # (1)

    def application(environ, start_response):
        os.environ['USER'] = environ['USER']

    # (2) I have to put the following two lines here, but would like them at (1)
    import django.core.handlers.wsgi
    _application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

**Problem**
This code works, and actually does what I want. I believe the import inside the application function is not a problem, since the application function is only called when Apache loads my app (I believe). However, putting the two lines at (2) at (1) would give me an `KeyError` in my `settings.py` file. The reason is, that the call to `WSGIHandler()` causes the `settings.py`to be loaded. And since I access the `os.environ` values in `settings.py`, I get a `KeyError`.
I initially followed the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102620/django-get-environment-variables-from-apache) similar SO question, but it gives me the above problem.

**Question**
Can I handle the passing of Apache environment variables to my Django application in a better way? I believe I am missing something, and it is the first time I set up Django on a production server.