# Passing environment variables from apache via mod_wsgi to use in django 1.11 settings

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Found a few versions of this question, such as [Django get environment variables from apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102620/django-get-environment-variables-from-apache), however the advice I've found so far doesn't seem to work with the latest LTS django (1.11).

I have an apache configuration which holds a number of environment variables, not limited to connection credentials for the DB. Im using this to make my code portable between dev/prod etc.

My apache conf just uses SetEnv to pass in some variables.

I've tried two different styles of approach to use these variables, both seem to suffer from the same issue; it needs to read the settings file before we can write to the environment, and the settings file requires values from the environment.

My two variants are;

```
import os
import django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

_application = get_wsgi_application()

def application(environ, start_response):
  for key in [keys...]:
    if environ.get(key):
        os.environ[key] = environ.get(key)
  return _application(environ, start_response)
```

and

```
import os
import django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

class WSGIEnvironment(WSGIHandler):
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        for key in [keys...]:
            if environ.has_key(key):
                print "Key: %s = %s" % (key,environ[key])
                os.environ[key] = environ[key]
        return super(WSGIEnvironment, self).__call__(environ, start_response)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'apiClient.settings')
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
application = WSGIEnvironment()
```

Either way im trying to use the values in settings as;

```
KEY = "thing"

if os.environ.has_key("KEY"):
    KEY = os.environ["KEY"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `SetEnv` as the settings file is evaluated before the first request is handled. Setting environment variables from per request WSGI environ values was always a bad idea and can cause problems, so you shouldn't do that anyway.

Result is that you cannot set environment variables from the Apache configuration file. Set them from the WSGI script file. If they are things that should not be added to a Git repository, create a file on the specific host with the values in some format, and have the WSGI script file read that file from the local host to set them when first loaded and before any Django code is executed.

Comment: It wasn't so much as the files couldn't go in git, it was more that the code is entirely transportable between different deploys with the exception of things like database host etc, which vary per deploy (obviously). The apache environment seemed like a nice distinct configuration. Disappointing.

Comment: Could you give an example? It seems as though many solutions on the web suggest writing to os.environ from the environ passed to the application (e.g. http://ericplumb.com/blog/passing-apache-environment-variables-to-django-via-mod_wsgi.html)

Comment: Personally I regard setting `os.environ` on each request as bad practice. It can cause problems in multi threaded apps, especially when the value could change. I outlined recommended solution.

Answer (score 1):

For Django > 1.7 get_wsgi_application calls django.setup() which initializes the settings. So if your env vars aren't set at that point you won't see them in the settings.

To get around it, don't actually call get_wsgi_application until you're ready. This works for me in wsgi.py:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    os.environ['APPLICATION_ENV'] = environ.get('APPLICATION_ENV', None)
    return get_wsgi_application()(environ, start_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to defer initialising the Django app until the first request. Something like this in your wsgi.py:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
_application = None
def application(environ, start_response):
    global _application
    if _application == None:
        for key in environ:
            if key.startswith('ENV_'):
                os.environ[key[4:]] = environ[key]
        _application = get_wsgi_application()
    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

It's a pity that there appears to be no option in mod_wsgi to set the initial environment when starting the daemon process, as you can with mod_fastcgi.

Comment: Setting environment variables per request like this is not a very good practice. Should never do this if running more than one WSGI application in embedded mode or in same daemon process group. Also generally a bad idea if using embedded mode and running non Python applications such as PHP in same Apache. This is because you muck up the environment of the other applications. Right now the preferred mechanism is to set them from the WSGI script file, or via some file read/imported from the WSGI script file.

Comment: Is this not the wsgi script file? It certainly seems to be